# What is the difference between self.managedObjectContext and managedObjectInstance.managedObjectContext?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

So, I have the CoreData entities `Book`, `Bookmark`, `Highlight`. A book contains information about the book and an `NSSet` of `Bookmarks`.

I want to delete the bookmarks present in one book and then immediately repopulate them with my set.

This is a code that I have got from another project and I can not seem to get why they have used different kinds of `deleteObject` method.

They go like:

```
for (Bookmark *bookmark in book.bookmarks) {
    [bookmark.mamagedObjectContext deleteObject:bookmark];
}
```

What's the difference between using `self.managedObjectContext` and `bookmark.managedObjectContext`. Also, either doesn't seem to have any effect on the contents and I get an error while trying to delete all the bookmarks in the `forin` loop and then adding a new set by a `forin` loop again.

Please mention in comments if more information is required.

Comment: That `for` loop should not be used because `forin` loops are not allowed to modify the collection.

Comment: @sosborn This perfectly correct in CD since object are only marked to be deleted. When the lifecycle reaches the end, CD removes the objects in the persistent store.

Answer (score 2):

The `managedObjectInstance.managedObjectContext` returns the managed object context with which the receiver is registered.

In other words, if you created, for example, a bookmark in the main thread context (the one associated with the context created in the main thread), `bookmark.managedObjectContext` will point to that.

Are you using different threads? Different contexts? What type of error do you have? Share it adding an edit to your question.